# How I make a list of missing integer from a sequence using bash

Tags: bash, shell, perl, awk

I have a file let's say **files_190911.csv** whose contents are as follows.

> EDR_MPU023_**09**_20190911080534.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU023_**10**_20190911081301.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU023_**11**_**20190911083544**.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU023_**14**_20190911091405.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU023_**15**_20190911105513.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU023_**16**_20190911105911.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU024_**50**_20190911235332.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU024_**51**_20190911235400.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU024_**52**_**20190911235501**.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU024_**54**_20190911235805.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU024_**55**_20190911235937.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU025_**24**_20190911000050.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU025_**25**_20190911000155.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU025_**26**_**20190911000302**.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU025_**29**_20190911000624.csv.gz

I want to make a list of missing sequence from those using bash script. 
 
Every **MPUXXX** has its own sequence. So there are multiple series of sequences in that file.
The datetime for missing list will use from previous sequence. 
 
From the sample above, the result will be like this.

> EDR_MPU023_**12_20190911083544**.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU023_**13_20190911083544**.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU024_**53_20190911235501**.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU025_**27_20190911000302**.csv.gz
>   EDR_MPU025_**28_20190911000302**.csv.gz

It would be simpler if there were only a single sequence. 
So I can use something like this.

```
awk '{for(i=p+1; i<$1; i++) print i} {p=$1}'
```

But I know this can't be used for multiple sequence.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: @John1024 well noted sir, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED** (Thanks @Cyrus!)

AWK is your friend:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

BEGIN {
    FS="[^0-9]*"
    last_seq = 0;
    next_serial = 0;
}

{
    cur_seq = $2;
    cur_serial = $3;
    if (cur_seq != last_seq) {
        last_seq = cur_seq;
        ts = $4
        prev = cur_serial;
    } else {
        if (cur_serial == next_serial) {
            ts = $4;
        } else {
            for (i = next_serial; i < cur_serial; i++) {
                print "EDR_MPU" last_seq "_" i "_" ts ".csv.gz"
            }
        }
    }
    next_serial = cur_serial + 1;
}
```

And then you do:

```
$ < files_190911.csv awk -f script.awk 
EDR_MPU023_12_20190911083544.csv.gz
EDR_MPU023_13_20190911083544.csv.gz
EDR_MPU024_53_20190911235501.csv.gz
EDR_MPU025_27_20190911000302.csv.gz
EDR_MPU025_28_20190911000302.csv.gz
```

The assignment to `FS=` splits lines by the regex. The rest program detects holes in sequences and prints them with the appropriate timestamp.

Comment: To get rid of `sed` with GNU `awk`: Add to your BEGIN section `FS="[^0-9]*"` and replace both `$3` with `$4`, `$2` with `$3` and `$1` with `$2`.

Comment: I wasn't aware that `FS` could be a regex - post edited - Thanks @Cyrus!!

Comment: From `man awk` (GNU awk): *If FS is a single character, fields are separated by that character. If FS is the null string, then each individual character becomes a separate field. Otherwise, FS is expected to be a full regular expression.*

Comment: just wanna make sure `[^0-9]` means NOT ONE of the characters right?

Comment: Correct, `^` it means none of the rest of the characters appearing within the brackets.